# how to get certain columns from dynamodb aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

[image]

I want to get only timestamp, address, distance, and proximity from DynamoDB using Lambda function, so that I can get the response at API Gateway to display on my React Native app.
May I know what's wrong with my Lambda function code?

```
import boto3
import json

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    IRAPID_BEACON = 'irapid_beacon'
    
    DDB_RESOURCE = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    IRAPID_BEACON_DDB_TABLE = DDB_RESOURCE.Table(IRAPID_BEACON)
    
    result = IRAPID_BEACON_DDB_TABLE.get_item(Key={'timestamp'}, ProjectionExpression='#timestamp, address, distance, proximity', ExpressionAttributeNames={'#address': 'address'})
    
    return {
        'body': result
    }
```

This is the response I get:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Key, value: {'timestamp'}, type: <class 'set'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "requestId": "3af15dff-d323-49bf-9429-bfce2d26e579",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    result = IRAPID_BEACON_DDB_TABLE.get_item(Key={'timestamp'}, ProjectionExpression='#timestamp, address, distance, proximity', ExpressionAttributeNames={'#address': 'address'})\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/resources/factory.py\", line 520, in do_action\n    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/boto3/resources/action.py\", line 83, in __call__\n    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 691, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 739, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 360, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by this:

```
import boto3
import json

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    
    IRAPID_BEACON = 'irapid_beacon'
    DDB_RESOURCE = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    IRAPID_BEACON_TABLE = DDB_RESOURCE.Table(IRAPID_BEACON)
    
    projection_expression = '#attr1, #attr2, #attr3, #attr4'
    
    expression_attribute_names = {
        '#attr1': 'timestamp',
        '#attr2': 'address',
        '#attr3': 'distance',
        '#attr4': 'proximity',
    }
    
    scan_params = {
        'TableName': IRAPID_BEACON,
        'ProjectionExpression': projection_expression,
        'ExpressionAttributeNames': expression_attribute_names
    }

    response = dynamodb.scan(**scan_params)
    
    data = response['Items']
    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = IRAPID_BEACON_TABLE.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        data.extend(response['Items'])
        
    return data
```

The result I got:

```
[
  {
    "proximity": {
      "S": "IMMEDIATE"
    },
    "address": {
      "S": "E3:60:15:DA:38:E2"
    },
    "distance": {
      "N": "0.013031512640464739"
    },
    "timestamp": {
      "N": "1679536528228"
    }
  },
  {
    "proximity": {
      "S": "FAR"
    },
    "address": {
      "S": "C7:EE:CA:83:FA:AC"
    },
    "distance": {
      "N": "60.536073313879164"
    },
    "timestamp": {
      "N": "1679476131297"
    }
  }, ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you take a deep dive into DynamoDB documentation. I don't believe your data model will do what you expect.

If you want to do a `GetItem` you must provide the value of the partition key, in your case the timestamp.

```
Key={'timestamp': '<some time stamp value>'}
```

Its important to note that having timestamp as the partition key provides you very little query flexibility, it is also an issue if 2 items are written at the same time, one item would overwrite the other.

With your current schema, you would need to do a Scan with a FilterExpression which would be highly inefficient.

My suggestion depending on your throughput would be to use a static partition key value and timestamp as sort key. This will allow you do things like "give me all the items between this time range" or "give me the item at this specific time"

| PK | SK | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1680332401000 | other |
| 1 | 1680332412345 | other |
| 1 | 1680332402222 | other |

Using `Query` you can now do things like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK=1 AND SK > 1680332401000
```

Note that this would assume you do not write to the table more than 1000 RPS. If you do, then you would need to [shard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html) the PK by `#no of reqs/1000`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the error message, you should specify a value in your `Key` parameter:

```
Key={'timestamp': '1680332401551'}
```

Comment: but what if i have many items to get? and the data is real-time data